# Resolving gomock import cycle

Tags: go, gomock

How do I go about resolving an import cycle between `github.com/golang/mock/gomock` and `golang.org/x/net/context`? As far as I can tell this cycle exists internally between the two package and I can't modify either of them internally.

Currently these are my imports:

```
import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2" //mock
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)
```

And this is the exact error message I am receiving when running `withmock go test`:

```
ERROR: Failed to install 'gopkg.in/mgo.v2': exit status 1
output:
import cycle not allowed
package gopkg.in/mgo.v2
    imports github.com/golang/mock/gomock
    imports golang.org/x/net/context
    imports github.com/golang/mock/gomock
```

Comment: Have you tried updating gomock and context?  Because as far as I can tell, the current version of the x/net/context package does not import gomock.

Comment: Those import don't produce a cycle. Something is out of date on your system, or you've modified one of those packages.

Comment: I've tried running `go get -u github.com/golang/mock/gomock` and `go get -u github.com/golang/mock/gomock` and then `go install` on both packages. Still getting the same cycle issue though.

Comment: Interestingly grepping the `$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/net/` folder for `gomock` finds no matches.

Comment: Do you have gomock or context vendored?